# jQueryUI tooltip for validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I use jQueryUI tooltip for validation.

I just want exactly do this: when Textbox focusout or sumbit button click empty textbox tooltip appear. I write this script but this script have this problem:

1. on click or Mouseover or Mouseout ... in Textbox the tooltip does not appear.just on focusout or sumbit button
2. tooltip not disappear just disappear when user click in it.

[Fiddler Link](http://jsfiddle.net/WmRuN/269/)

```
    .errorClass { border:  1px solid red; }
<div id="#tooltip">
<lable ><input id="FName" name="FName" type="text" title="my FName" />
<br/><br/>
    <input id="Post" maxlength="200" name="Post" title="my Post" type="text" value=""><br/><br/>
         <input type="submit" value="sumbit" class="insertBtn" onclick="return ISValidInfo()" />
        <div>
 $(function () {
        $("#tooltip").tooltip().off("mouseover mouseout ");      
        $("#FName").focusout(function () {
            ISValidFname();
        });
        $("#Post").focusout(function () {
            ISValidPost();
        });
        function ISValidFname() {
            if (!$.trim($('#FName').val())) {
                $("#FName").addClass("errorClass")
                $("#FName").tooltip({
                    position: {
                       at: "right top",
                        my: "left bottom",
                    }
                });
                $("#FName").tooltip("open");
            }
            else {
                $("#FName").removeClass("errorClass")
            }
        }
        function ISValidPost() {
            if (!$.trim($('#Post').val())) {
                $("#Post").addClass("errorClass")
                $("#Post").tooltip({
                    position: {
                        at: "right top",
                        my: "left bottom",
                    }
                });
                $("#Post").tooltip("open");
            }
            else {
                $("#Post").removeClass("errorClass")
            }
        }

    function ISValidInfo() {
        ISValidFname();
        ISValidPost();
    }
});
```

Comment: In fiddle, tooltip does appear on mouseover...

Comment: I want not this happen.how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/WmRuN/273/) that might help.

I moved the defined functions out of the main function, and changed a few lines.

JS

```
$(function () {
      $("#tooltip").tooltip();      
      $("#FName").focusout(function () {
                                        ISValidFname();
                                        });
      $("#Post").focusout(function () {
                                        ISValidPost();
                                        });
});

function ISValidFname()
{
 if ( !$.trim($('#FName').val() ) )
    {
     $("#FName").addClass("errorClass")
     $("#FName").tooltip({
                          position: {
                                     my: "left top",
                                     at: "right top"
                                     }
                          });
     $("#FName").tooltip("open");
     } else {
             $("#FName").removeClass("errorClass")
             }
}

function ISValidPost()
{
 if (!$.trim($('#Post').val())) {
            $("#Post").addClass("errorClass")
            $("#Post").tooltip({
                                position: {
                                           my: "left top",
                                           at: "right top"
                                           }
                                });
            $("#Post").tooltip("open");
            } else {
                    $("#Post").removeClass("errorClass")
                    }
}

function ISValidInfo()
{
  ISValidFname();
  ISValidPost();
}
```

Comment: after tooltip appear on mouseover  it disapear.how can i fix that

Comment: I've looked around a bit, and I can't find a way to keep it open until it is "valid". You probably need to write some code without the tooltip.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with pure css with similar functionality - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/WmRuN/275/

Comment: this take space.i want something like tooltip

Answer (score 1):

If you want your tool-tip to appear only on focus-in and disable on focus out. Try this:

```
$("#tooltip").tooltip({
    disabled: true
}).on("focusin", function () {
    $(this)
        .tooltip("enable")
        .tooltip("open");
}).on("focusout", function () {
    $(this)
        .tooltip("close")
        .tooltip("disable");
});
```

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WmRuN/)

A shorter way is:

```
$("#tooltip").tooltip().off("mouseover mouseout ");
```

Which I see in your code but is not working properly..

Comment: this answer is completely different from what i want